# Is there an URL I can use to redirect another URL through a proxy?

Tags: url, redirect, proxy, vpn

France has recently blocked access to sci-hub and libgen. Before, I used to access them in one-click using the "manage engine search" of Google Chrome. I typed "sci" + [spacebar] + DOI/URL of the paper I was interested in, and I would access it directly. Indeed, this was a shortcut to type e.g. `http://sci-hub.tw/%s` where `%s` is my research.
Now, I have to pass through a proxy to access these sites, so I cannot use the same trick anymore.

Does anyone know an URL like `http://proxy.com/%URL` to access the `%URL` I want through a proxy? (e.g. `http://proxy.com/http://sci-hub.tw/%s`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use England's `goawaycameron` (`Gom` now) which we developed to do the same thing but with porn.

It's a browser plugin so you can use it "hands free"

Comment: Thank you. There are hundreds of browser plugins but this is not what I am looking for. I am looking for an URL.

Answer (score 0):

One can use a proxy website such as [hide.me/proxy](https://hide.me/proxy) and uncheck the option `Encrypt URL`. For example, accessing the search `%s` on sci-hub would go by typing `https://nl.hideproxy.me/go.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fsci-hub.tw%2F%s&b=4&f=norefer` in the address bar.